# How to open multiple consoles in multiple tabs in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, console, perspective

I am using Eclipse Version: Helios Release for a Java application. I need to run multiple instances of same application and want easy visibility of multiple consoles.

Can it be done? If yes, how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run the application twice (say instance A and B). Console will display message from B. Then create two consoles as rsilva pointed (say 1 and 2). Both consoles will show message from B. After that change console 1 to display message from A by selecting the arrow near icon with monitor and select the instance A. The message from instance A will be displayed on console 1.

You can of course drag (or detached) one console to other place for better visibility.

Comment: But i will have to do it every time? Isnt there any permanent solution like in netbeans?

Comment: sorry.. not familiar with netbeans. Maybe others can help you

Answer (score 12):

Just look for your console view and in the right top click on the 'Open Console' button and select 'New console view'

Comment: ok... what next?
I dont think that you understood my question

Comment: I want all instances in tabs format. I dont want to click on 'Open Selected Console' everytime i need to switch to a different console.

Comment: ok I see what you mean now. You have to turn off the 'Show Console When Stardard Out Changes' and the error one too. Do this in all the views. Now the views will stay in the the console you selected.

Answer (score 1):

If you write out your console information to multiple logs, then you can use a utility called [Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) which is highly configurable and easy to use.  It allows you to view a growing file, i.e. logs for example, in realtime.  Its easy to use and highly configurable - might be of some help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Located near your console tab should be a button "Open Console".
If you click this button one of your options should be "New Console View".

You'll now have 2 console views.

One of your other buttons near your console tab is "Display Selected Console". When you choose this option you can select from any of your running applications.
Just select the tab, select which application you want it to watch, and repeat for the other tab.
You can then move your 2 console views to wherever you want independently of each other.