# Is it possible to open 2 consoles in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, console

I launch the Eclipse debugger for the 2 applications and I would like while debugging to watch the output of the application. How can I achieve that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This has already been asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203339/how-to-open-multiple-consoles-in-multiple-tabs-in-eclipse